# Is it possible to make a crontab using daemon?

Tags: cron, daemon

We were asked to make a whole cron stuff, not making the cron job but the actual cron that will work with the date/time that we input to them.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a whole new daemon you can help yourself with some samples from cron source code: 
[Link 1](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/39189706/)
[Link 2](https://github.com/cronie-crond/cronie)

Or if you want to create your API to interact with the cron daemon , there is a big chance that has been already made  , so just search for the given language and you can read the source and help yourself with some parts.